# Split image frame into 8*8 for DCT using OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, split, dct

I need to pass fullPath into method FrameTo8by8(). In FrameTo8by8(), it will split the every frame into 8*8 blocks. (E.g. My video resolution is 1280*720 = 921,600. After that 921,600 / 64(8*8) = 14,400. So there will be total of 14,400 blocks of 8*8).

**VideoSplitEngine.h**

```
class VideoSplitEngine
{
    public:

    static VideoCapture capture;
    static Mat fullimage;

    //Default constructor
    VideoSplitEngine();

    //Declare a virtual destructor:
    virtual ~VideoSplitEngine();

    //Method
    Mat Start();    
    void FrameTo8by8() const; 
    string GetFilePath() const;

    private:
};
```

**VideoSplitEngine.cpp**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "VideoSplitEngine.h"
#include "UserInfo.h"
#include "Common.h"

VideoCapture VideoSplitEngine::capture;

Mat VideoSplitEngine::fullimage;

Mat VideoSplitEngine::Start()

string VideoSplitEngine::GetFilePath() const
{
  cout<< endl;
  cout << "Place video in Desktop and enter file name (e.g. vid.avi):" << endl;
  cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<< endl;

  //Get user desktop file path
  string fullPath;
  string userProfile = getenv("userprofile");   //GetEnvironmentVariable() is to get current userprofile (e.g."C:\Users\L30807")
  string path = userProfile + "\\Desktop\\";
  string vid;

  getline (cin, vid);       //Prompt to input file name
  fullPath = path + vid;
  capture.open(fullPath); //Read video
  cout<< endl;

  return fullPath;
}

Mat VideoSplitEngine::Start()
{
  while(1)
  {
    bool bSuccess = capture.read(fullimage); // read a new frame from video

    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "End of video" << endl;
        destroyWindow("Original Video");
        break;
    }

    imshow("Original Video", fullimage); //show the frame in "Original Video" window

    if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
    {
        cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl; 
        break; 
    }
  }

return fullimage;
}

void VideoSplitEngine::FrameTo8by8() const
{
    namedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
    imshow("Original", fullimage); 

    int width = fullimage.size().width; 
    int height = fullimage.size().width; 

    cout << "Original image Width x Height is " << width << "x" << height << endl; 

    // Leave original alone, work on a copy 
    Mat dctImage = fullimage.clone();

    // Step through the copied image with rectangles size 8x8 
    // For each block, split into planes, do dct, and merge back 
    // into the block. (This will affect the image from 
    // which the block is selected each time.) 

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i += 8) 
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j+= 8) 
        {
            Mat block = dctImage(Rect(i, j, 8, 8));
            vector<Mat> planes; 
            split(block, planes);
            vector<Mat> outplanes(planes.size());

            for (size_t k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++)
            {
                planes[k].convertTo(planes[k], CV_32FC1); 
                dct(planes[k], outplanes[k]);
                outplanes[k].convertTo(outplanes[k], CV_8UC1);
            }
                merge(outplanes, block); 
        } 
    } 

    namedWindow("dctBlockImage"); 
    imshow("dctBlockImage", dctImage);

    waitKey(30); 
}
```

I need help on how to split it or is there other methods to do it?

Comment: looks a bit clumsy, but should work at least. do you really need the merged dct of 3 color channels ? or rather make it grayscale in the beginning, and operate on 1 plane only ?

Comment: I can't seems to get it working. I need to merged dct of 3 RGB color channels.

Comment: ok. so what goes wrong ? and please make it: `dctImage(Rect(j, i, 8, 8));`

Comment: this error came out "Unhandled exception at 0x767ec42d in VideoWM.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0031e6cc.."

Comment: Alright manage to solve the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3743939 If you managed to solve your problem please post it as an answer to help other people that stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 2):

1.@berak is right.The prototype of function Rect() is Rect(x,y,width,height).So 'j' which refer to 'width' should be 'x'.(Actually I havn't found the prototype of Rect() from http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/index.html ,but cvRect() in the C API is cvRect(x,y,width,height).I think their prototypes maybe the same.)

2.`for (int i = 0; i < height; i += 8)` and `for (int j = 0; j < width; j+= 8)` will cause the error ""Unhandled exception at ...".By changing them to `for (int i = 0; i < (height/8)*8; i += 8)`and`for (int j = 0; j < (width/8)*8; j+= 8)`,this error will be sovled.

3.@user3743939 If you managed to sovle your problem,please post your solution to help others.

regards